# How to generate PDF of an action method in ASP.NET MVC 4 application having .NET framework 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, pdf-generation, asp.net-4.0

I tried **Rotativa**, **RazorPDF**, **ABCpdf**. But they aren't working when I make a project with *.NET framework 4.0*. They are working fine with *.NET framework 4.5 or above*. I searched in google, but didn't find any satisfactory answer for me. (I want to avoid RDLC report here).

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0):

Try Debenu Quick PDF. Just Add the dll and you have some fonction to generate PDF.

Here is the link of the official website : http://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library/

You have many examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try NReco PDF Generator. We've been using it within our company for a while now and it works good. Plus-side is that it's free.

Check out http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx for download and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DynamicPDF .NET libraries](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/.NET-PDF-Library.aspx), there are several of them that supports .NET Framework 4.0. If you want to generate new PDFs or modify/merge existing PDFs then check out [DynamicPDF Core Suite for .NET](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/PDF-Suite-.NET.aspx). In case you want to convert different file types (HTML, Word, Excel, PowerPoint etc) to PDF then take a look at the [DynamicPDF Converter for .NET](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/PDF-Conversion-.NET.aspx).

Disclaimer: I work for ceTe Software, the company that develops DynamicPDF libraries.